# Automapper: mapping RedisValue from StackExchange.Redis StreamEntry to an object strange behavior

Tags: c#, automapper, stackexchange.redis

I encountered some strange behavior while mapping StreamEntry from StackExchange.Redis library to a C# record. While I found the way to write the mapping to make it work, I still do not understand, why does it work only this way (probably due to limited knowledge of AutoMapper internals). Also, I think this could be an example to anyone who hits this problem itself.

Short introduction:
I was migrating .Net 5 project using StackExchange.Redis & AutoMapper to .Net 6, same time updating all the packages used. Automapper became version 11 and StackExchange.Redis version 2.2.88.
When I ran our unit tests, mapping validation suddenly failed. I didn't change a lot in mappings, replaced only ForAllOtherMembers with ForAllMembers and it was quite strange for me.

The problem itself:
`.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))` directive is invalid if src object is StreamEntry. It just throws error "Error mapping types." on validation like if there was no mapping!

Solution:
After some trying around, I've managed to find out that you should use not `MapFrom<TSourceMember>(Expression<Func<TSource, TSourceMember>> mapExpression)`, but `MapFrom<TResult>(Func<TSource, TDestination, TResult> mappingFunction)` and everything works. So just changing code line above to `.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, _) => src.Id))` magically fixed everything.

Questions:

1. Why? I think this is related to how RedisValue is implemented, but I really don't understand why it stopped working in .Net 6 with AutoMapper 11.
2. To map all members that have string type we use `.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src[opt.DestinationMember.Name]))` and it still work as it was, however if you try to replace it with `.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom((src, _) => src[opt.DestinationMember.Name]))`, it will break.

.Net 6 console example that shows both of issues and correct way to map could be found [here](https://github.com/PeshekhonovK/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/Automapper.Net6/Automapper.Net6/Program.cs). TLDR: Configurations A & C are invalid and B is how it should be done.

Comment: See also https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/3833.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are usage errors. `ForAllMembers`, as the name indicates, will overwrite your custom config.
Just don't write code like that.

Comment: First of all, yes, ForAllMembers does remove the issue. However, why does it work with ForAllMembers and MapFrom<TResult>(Func<TSource, TDestination, TResult> mappingFunction)?

Also there is no ForAllOtherMembers now, so how should we do cases when all members except one or two should be mapped same way? Copy/paste ForMember?

And in case of using .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom((src, _) => src[opt.DestinationMember.Name])) it still maps correctly

Comment: Because a `Func` has priority over `Expression`, but really, this kind of code is just looking for trouble. In the future we might explicitly reset all per member config.

Comment: Thank you! I will then write our own version of ForAllOtherMembers probably, as for StreamEntry case it's quite a useful thing (and generally for mapping dictionary-like entities to an objects), so would be great if you somehow add something like this :)

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: Yeah, would be great if it was normal dynamic or dictionary, however it's a custom struct that exposes explicit
public RedisValue this[RedisValue fieldName] { get { ... } }
So it is dictionary-like, but not real dictionary. I don't think there is any support for such cases

Comment: Obviously :) So all you can do is go through a dictionary.